# jquery autocomplete transformResult auto focus property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

Now it is looking like this 
    [image]

I am workingin jquery autocomplete below is my code where i want to search city.

```
jQuery('#citySearch').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: basePath + '/selectMycities.json',
        paramName: "tagName", // 
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            cityID = suggestion.data;
            cityId=cityID;
            jQuery("#cityId").val(cityID);
            return false;
        },
        transformResult: function(response) {

            return {

                suggestions: jQuery.map(jQuery.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.cityName,
                        data: item.cityId,
                        id: item.cityId
                    };

                })
            };
        }
    });
```

Now in above autocomplete i want to set autoFocus as true but it is not working. please help.

It should like 2nd image

[image]

Comment: jQuery('#citySearch').autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true, // rest of param.....

Comment: Please provide fiddle or plunkr for better answer

Comment: @Jugnu please have look at the updated question  i have added images for this.

Comment: @Jugnu found the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution with reference to these https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

I used autoSelectFirst property and i got the respected result as like 2nd image.

autoSelectFirst: if set to true, first item will be selected when showing suggestions. Default value false.

```
jQuery('#citySearch').autocomplete({
        autoSelectFirst: true,
        serviceUrl: basePath + '/selectMycities.json',
        paramName: "tagName", // 
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            cityID = suggestion.data;
            cityId=cityID;
            jQuery("#cityId").val(cityID);
            return false;
        },
        transformResult: function(response) {

            return {

                suggestions: jQuery.map(jQuery.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                    return {
                        value: item.cityName,
                        data: item.cityId,
                        id: item.cityId
                    };

                })
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: You was using other autocomplete than default jquery auto-complete that's why it wan't working???

Answer (score 0):

u have to add

```
$( "#citySearch" ).focus();
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/1vfcgcco/1/

or something like this...

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({ 
source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(src, request.term);

    response(results.slice(0, 4));
 }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqwBP/1098/

Comment: it is not working at my end. please view updated question with the uploaded image

Comment: both images are exactly same, are u looking for this-> http://jsfiddle.net/vqwBP/1098/

Comment: they are not same 2nd image is highlighted first element in search. and the jquery autocomplete in jsfiddle you have given is different from the jquery autocomplete i have used.

Comment: please add a fiddle , so that we can work on ur fiddle, yeah i have used this autocomplete because i dont have ur resource. If this is correct, we can implement that in ur code.

Answer (score 0):

autofocus will highlight first item,  while selectFirst will select first item.

```
 jQuery('#citySearch').autocomplete({
            selectFirst: true,
            autoFocus: true,
            serviceUrl: basePath + '/selectMycities.json',
            paramName: "tagName", // 
            onSelect: function(suggestion) {
                cityID = suggestion.data;
                cityId=cityID;
                jQuery("#cityId").val(cityID);
                return false;
            },
            transformResult: function(response) {

                return {

                    suggestions: jQuery.map(jQuery.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.cityName,
                            data: item.cityId,
                            id: item.cityId
                        };

                    })
                };
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for reply but as i said these properties are not working at my end. I think for transformResult type of jquery autocomplete there are different properties for same function.

Comment: Please provide fiddle so i can see whats going on your side. Hope you know how to make fiddle ????